# Excel VBA to Quickbooks Online Link?

Tags: excel, quickbooks-online, vba

Is there any way I can write an Excel VBA program to interface with Quickbooks online? I work for a company that uses quickbooks for accounting, and I'd like to write a simple program that I can run from one of our common excel files to take data from that file and dump into in a Quickbooks bill.

The problem Im running in to is that I dont know where to start. The quickbooks online API online seems suitable for other web apps, and any integration with Excel is online with quickbooks desktop. Are there any good resources? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the [QuickBooks Online API](https://developer.intuit.com/us#QuickBooksOnlineAPI) to do what you're looking to do.

The API is usable to both web apps and desktop apps. 
If you follow the linked text above there's tons of documentation.

The basic process if you're building a desktop app would be to:

- get your OAuth tokens from Intuit's OAuth playground
- find an OAuth library for your language of choice
- parse the Excel sheet
- send OAuth signed REST requests to Intuit's API to send the data to QBO

If you're building a web app instead, you'd be better off implementing the entire OAuth signup process instead of using the playground tool.

You probably don't want to do this *from directly within Excel* because there's a lot of OAuth signing and other crazy stuff that likely won't be easy/available within Excel directly. But you should be able to use Intuit's [.NET DevKit](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits) to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this last month. From what I can tell the API is only for creating apps for their app store. The apps have to comply with their standards for navigation, security etc...  so the answer to your question from what I can tell is that it's not possible. (I could be wrong but I was asking myself the same question a few weeks ago.)

Probably not the answer you were hoping for but I came to accept it. After talking with my business partner who is a Pro Adviser he said that it was easy enough for him to just upload a csv file if the information was correct and the file was documented.

[QuickBooks Online API Diagnostics.php ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651453/quickbooks-online-api-diagnostics-php-error?rq=1) However, from the looks of this post one might have a reason to believe otherwise.

**EDIT** The API has been updated. Keith Palmer's answer is correct.

Comment: Intuit changed their policies last month so that ANYONE can use the QuickBooks Online API - you don't have to be selling an app to use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Last week this sample was posted:
[OAuthHangoutSamples](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/OAuthHangoutSamples/tree/master/DistributedDesktopApp)

I have been using a modified oAuth part of this.  I found it was easier to build out the transaction than use the SDK for the API.  I have a wrapper class, exposed to com that is working in VBA.

Attending the Intuit's Friday Developer Google Hangout was very helpful in my Intuit Magical Mystery Tour.